# Generic type and field accessing in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

Instead of T (Type) if I use class name i.e. sampleclass this code works properly,
but if I use T, then it shows that

> 'T' does not contain a definition for 'TimeStamp' and no accessible
>   extension method 'TimeStamp' accepting a first argument of type 'T'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

```
//Get collection.
var collection = this.GetDatabaseConnection().GetCollection<T>
    (collectionName);
//filter to read specific data.
var filter = Builders<T>.Filter.Where(result => result.TimeStamp >=
    startTime && result.TimeStamp <= endTime);
List < T > queryData = collection.Find<T>(filter, null).ToList();
```

Previously it was as follows and working finely:

```
//Get collection.
var collection = this.GetDatabaseConnection().GetCollection<Sampleclass>.
    (collectionName);
//filter to read data using specific timestamp.
var filter = Builders<Sampleclass>.Filter.Where(result =>
    result.TimeStamp >=
    startTime && result.TimeStamp <= endTime);
List < Sampleclass > queryData = collection.Find<Sampleclass>
    (filter, null).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `T` doesn't have a `TimeStamp` property as it's a generic type. If you always have to access the `TimeStamp` of whatever type you process in your collection, you could consider using an interface that has `TimeStamp` as a get function. All the types you want to process would have to implement that interface.

```
public interface MyInterface 
{
    TimeSpan TimeStamp { get; } //or whatever type your are using for your TimeStamp property
}


var collection = this.GetDatabaseConnection().GetCollection<MyInterface> 
    (collectionName);
var filter = Builders<MyInterface>.Filter.Where(result => result.TimeStamp >= 
    startTime && result.TimeStamp <= endTime);
List<MyInterface> queryData = collection.Find<MyInterface>(filter,null).ToList();
```

This way it's still quite generic. If you want to still use type `T` you would have to work with reflection to find the property `TimeStamp` on your processed type.

Edit: Some advice for using type `T`: You always have to consider that `T` can be anything, from an integer to any other object imaginable. Sometimes it can be quite useful if you have a method for example that doesn't need to access any properties on the type `T` object it is given but is used for many different types. I lately used T to build a little `ParseOrDefault` method to catch values that can't be converted:

```
private T ParseOrDefault<T>(Object value, T defaultValue)
{
    try
    {
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

As soon as you have to deal with more specific use cases `T` is mostly not that useful.

Comment: Thanks for reply, here i have two separate class having different different members but only that TimeStamp is present in both classes as member and while creating object of this class i will pass  name  i.e. sampleclass1 or sampleclass2 it should take based on this classes. here we can not pass MyInterface that will be specific not generic.

Comment: @Nil Why not? You can easily do `MyInterface sampleClass = new SampleClass(name)`

Comment: thanks this i tried but not worked for me, finally i came to different solution

Comment: if(typeof(T) == typeof(Sampleclass1)){var filter = Builders<Sampleclass1>.Filter.Where(result => result.TimeStamp >=
    startTime && result.TimeStamp <= endTime);
List < T > queryData = collection.Find<Sampleclass1>(filter, null).ToList();} else if (typeof(T) == typeof(MonitorSchema2)){ Builders<Sampleclass2>.Filter.Where(result => result.TimeStamp >=
    startTime && result.TimeStamp <= endTime);
List < T > queryData = collection.Find<Sampleclass2>(filter, null).ToList(); }

Comment: @Nil If your `SampleClass` implements `MyInterface` and has a constructor accepting a `name`, `MyInterface sampleClass = new SampleClass(name)` should be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

i would do it using a base class like this

```cs
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Program
    {
        public class Entity
        {
            [BsonId]
            public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
            public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
        }

        public class Sample : Entity
        {
            public string Something { get; set; }
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var collection = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017")
                                 .GetDatabase("Test")
                                 .GetCollection<Entity>("Samples");

            var sample = new Sample
            {
                Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId(),
                Something = "something",
                TimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow
            };

            collection.InsertOne(sample);

            var result = collection.AsQueryable()
                                   .Where(s =>
                                          s.TimeStamp >= DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1) &&
                                          s.TimeStamp <= DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1))
                                   .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case it is different iam having two different types of classes instead of sample and all CRUD operation related methods iam keeping in entity class and two sample class those having different members can be stored using this entity class

Comment: @Nil i think i understand your requirement now. have a look at my library [MongoDB.Entities](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoDB.Entities) it is a generic repository like you're trying to create. if you don't like to use a library, have a look at the source code to see how i've achieved generic CRUD operations. if you need further help, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

after reading your comments on my first answer, i'd like to propose the following solution using MongoDB.Entities

hope this is more or less what you're trying to achieve...

```cs
using MongoDB.Entities;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Program
    {
        public class MySample : Entity
        {
            public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
        }

        public class Sample1 : MySample
        {
            public string SomeProp { get; set; }
        }

        public class Sample2 : MySample
        {
            public string AnotherProp { get; set; }
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new DB("test");

            var sample1 = new Sample1 { SomeProp = "some prop value", TimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow };
            var sample2 = new Sample2 { AnotherProp = "another prop", TimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow };

            DB.Save(sample1);
            DB.Save(sample2);

            var s1 = FindSamples<Sample1>();
            var s2 = FindSamples<Sample2>();

            List<T> FindSamples<T>() where T : MySample
            {
                return DB.Find<T>()
                         .Many(s =>
                               s.TimeStamp >= DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1) &&
                               s.TimeStamp <= DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```